# Why does powershell env works locally but not with dockerfile?

Tags: git, powershell, dockerfile

So I ran this command on my local machine. Scrubbed link for obvious reasons.

```
scalar clone --full-clone https://$env:USERNAME:$env:PAT_TOKEN@<MY GIT REPO LINK HERE>
```

But running this doesn't work in a dockerfile. Even with the ARGs passed in during the build. And yes, I've checked them by printing them out.

```
RUN scalar clone --full-clone https://$env:USERNAME:$env:PAT_TOKEN@<MY GIT REPO LINK HERE>
```

But if I just add a back slash in the right place, it works...

```
RUN scalar clone --full-clone https://$env:USERNAME\:$env:PAT_TOKEN@<MY GIT REPO LINK HERE>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it works locally, because [you appear to have hit a *bug* (as of PowerShell 7.0)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13707), which can more simply be demonstrated thus:

```
# Command based on *Windows* environment vars., but the bug affects Unix too.
PS> Write-Output $env:OS:$env:USERNAME@more
jdoe@more  # !! only the *2nd* variable value is output.
```

The bug surfaces when two `$env:<name>` references are directly joined with a `:` (your insertion of `\` before the `:` bypassed the bug).

The workaround is to **enclose the variable name (including the `env:` namespace prefix) in `{...}`**, which is PowerShell's mechanism for disambiguating variable names from adjacent characters in (implicit) expandable strings:

```
# Workaround: enclose the variable name in {...}
PS> Write-Output ${env:OS}:$env:USERNAME@more
Windows_NT:jdoe@more  # OK.
```